# Next.js MySQL INSERT/UPDATE query never seems to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs, next.js

Quite the odd issue here.. I think this may be more of a problem of debugging, however I'm going to post in-case it is truly an issue and I'm quite frankly at my wits end anyway. I am doing a basic React.js/next.js form that takes a few inputs and adds them to state, then using axios sends the update to the api, which then makes a query insert or update to MySQL. The problem is, this Insert/Update doesn't work and I can't get any error output besides generic ETIMEDOUT from time to time, which I'm not even sure are related. I had this fixed before but am still unsure what I did. **ALL** other queries on the site work fine, the connection to the MySQL (AWS RDS) database is just fine.

My theories are A) the final query syntax has a silly issue causing this to just get lost in the abyss, or B) there's some server side code trying be run client side that I don't quite understand. (have also gotten the module 'fs' not found), or C) an async issue that I am not weathered enough in next.js to fix.  And before you say it, yes there is data to be updated in the table, it is not trying to update the same data and thus bypassing the update. It is new data, every time I test.

**NOTE-- I should also say, this code works PERFECT on my local osx environment. This ONLY happens when I try to run this on my Vercel deployment environment. This is important to know. The Database and Code are the EXACT same between both environments.**

Without further ado, some code:

To save code display, lets assume our values are in state and ready to go to the API, as I know for a fact they are, and they make it to the actual query.

**handleSubmit** - gets run when the form is submitted.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Loop data, create a list of IDs for the Delete and an 
        // array of array of arrays for the insert.
        let segmentItemIDList = [];
        const segmentItemArray = [];

        originalSegmentItemList = originalSegmentItemList.join(',')

        segmentItemState.map((val, idx) => (
            segmentItemArray[idx] = [
                segmentItemState[idx].segmentID,
                Number(segmentItemState[idx].chronologicalOrder),
                Number(segmentItemState[idx].releaseOrder),
                segmentItemState[idx].name,
                segmentItemState[idx].typeID
            ]
        ))

        let action = 'updatesegmentitem'
        axios.post('/api/list', { action, segmentItemArray })
          .then((result) => {

            action = 'deletesegmentitem'
            axios.post('/api/list', { action, originalSegmentItemList })
            .then((result) => {
                alert("Updated!!");
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
      }
```

**api/list** (assume it gets into this block, because it does)

```
else if(req.body.action == 'updatesegmentitem') {
            console.log("2. API updatesegmentitem req.body: ", req.body);

            const segmentItemArray = req.body.segmentItemArray;

            console.log("SegmentItemArray: ", segmentItemArray);

            try {
                if(Array.isArray(segmentItemArray) && segmentItemArray.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Inside IsArray: ", segmentItemArray);
                    const segmentItemInsertResults = await insertBatchSegmentItems(segmentItemArray);
                    res.send(segmentItemInsertResults);
                } else {
                    res.send(true);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                res.send('error');
            }
```

**insertBatchSegmentItems** (mysql query) .. Sometimes I get the console logs in here, sometimes not..

```
export async function insertBatchSegmentItems(segmentItemData) {
  let mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      debug: false,
  });

  mysqlConnection.connect();

  const insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO segmentItem (segmentID, chronologicalOrder, releaseOrder, name, typeID) VALUES ?'

  try {
    await mysqlConnection.query(insertSQL, [segmentItemData], function(err, result) {
      console.log("Connex Query Inside Result: ", result);
      if (err) throw err;
      //mysqlConnection.destroy();
      return result;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    //mysqlConnection.destroy();
    return e;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Please excuse my mess, I have been trying so many different things to try and get this to work but it will be cleaned up after a solution has been found.

Comment: what library do you use for mysql?

Comment: serverless-mysql.. I've actually redone this in the coming days and it seems to work. I am not sure what I did, but I will post the working solution soon just so maybe someone else can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into similar situations, I usually drop out exception handling and let it fail hard. It might give you a better insight of where it's happening. Good luck!

Comment: yes, good point. I will have to see if there's anything else I can do on that front. Fairly new to react/next.js framework so just working through each issue best I can :)